# Issue adding apple id in itunes connect for b2b

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, b2b

#### Background

My intention is to create a B2B app, for vpp distribution to a client in America.
I have an app approved, but retrospectively signed the required agreements for B2B distribution. I therefore have to create a new record which will be set for B2B, as you cannot set this post approval under the pricing tab.

I have also created a vpp account for test purposes

#### Problem

I have a new ios record in itunes connect, I have selected the B2B checkbox under the "pricing" tab.
The prompt to "add apple id's" appears, however there is no where to enter the username, and clicking "add apple id" button does nothing.

I have tried on several browsers (windows and mac) to check if it was an issue with the site (as i have noticed other css bugs), but to no avail

This seems to be the same issue as: [How do you add Apple ID's for a Custom B2B app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079735/how-do-you-add-apple-ids-for-a-custom-b2b-app), but there has been no action this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered on the post [How do you add Apple ID's for a Custom B2B app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079735/how-do-you-add-apple-ids-for-a-custom-b2b-app) - "It took over two weeks but as of 04-02-2015 iTunes connect has been fixed and you will be able to add Apple IDs for B2B apps."

I now have access to add the Apple ID via the input fields